# i18next render JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, internationalization, i18next

I want to render a JSON array

```
{"myArray": [ {"name": "Steve"}, {"name": "Tom"} ]}
```

in the two HTML `span`s:

```
<span data-i18n="...">Steve should appear here<span>
<span data-i18n="...">Tom should appear here<span>
```

What values should I set in `data-i18n` to achieve that, or can you recommend another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the JSON array that you are mentioning is part of your resource files (typically `translation.json`), then you can reference the elements of your array using their index, just like your reference object properties.

For your example, the following HTML will display what you expect when invoking `i18n()`:

```
<span data-i18n="myArray.0.name"><span>
<span data-i18n="myArray.1.name"><span>
```

Comment: Thank You, Coox! It is working: http://codepen.io/ngeorgiev/pen/hwcnD?editors=101